# Email validation regex C#

Tags: c#, regex, email

I have a regex which validate emails.

```
([a-z0-9_\.-]+\@[\da-z\.-]+\.[a-z\.]{2,6})
```

some emails start with "." "_" "-" and it catches it as a valid. How can I write a regex to start with characters or digits? I have text so anchor ^ doesn't working.

Regards

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**EDIT**
This question/answer should have been marked as the duplicate: [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address?rq=1)

---

Earlier this year I had the same need as you. Found out someone created a dedicated site for it: http://emailregex.com/

The regex posted there are according to RFC5322 and to my knowledge, works really well.

Also, to validate REGEX, I love [this site](https://regex101.com/).

Answer (score 1):

_test@example.com and -test@example.com are both valid per [RFC 822](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc0822.txt), you'd be better using a proper (non-regex) e-mail validator or perhaps by looking at [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116287/c-sharp-email-regular-expression-any-out-there-that-adhere-to-the-rfc-2822-gu).